# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 19999

Tags: java, spring, ssh, jsch, openssh

I have setup a java web application that executes this code to for reverse ssh

```
 FileInputStream hostFile = new FileInputStream(""+filePath);
 JSch jsch=new JSch();
 java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
 config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
 jsch.setKnownHosts(hostFile);
 Session session=jsch.getSession("centos", "192.168.0.8", 22); //THIS WORKS
 session.setConfig(config);
 session.setPassword(password);
 session.connect();
 session.setPortForwardingR(19999,"192.168.0.8",22); //FAILS HERE!!
```

However, the last line fails and throws the error:  com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 19999.

If I run the command from the command line, it works. So I am thinking the Jsch library is defective

```
 ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 centos@192.168.0.8
```

Answer (score 2):

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 19999
>   ...
>   If I run the command from the command line, it works

The simplest explanation is that, when your jsch session asked for the port forward, the remote server wasn't able to bind to port 19999 for some reason. Possibly because some other process was bound to that port. Possibly because one of your interactive commands was still running and bound to that port.

You could run `netstat` on the remote server to see if some other process is already using port 19999.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to keep running command by placing the code in while (true) loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change code from

```
session.setPortForwardingR(19999,"192.168.0.8",22);
```

to

```
session.setPortForwardingR(19999,"localhost",22);
```

Method is session.setPortForwardingR(rport, lhost, lport); so you should give localhost